# Install .apk without User action

Tags: android

I have one requirement of installing the apk without user intervention.

I know there is very straight forward way to install the apk programmatically but that requires the user action. I want the way where user action is not required and that will happen in background.

It is required because the user will have mandatory to install the apk.

I think there is no easy way to do this and it may require to write the own apk installer or some firmware.

Please share if you have some pointers on how to start with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds like something that would be impossible (without hacking), due to security issues. Just think of what could happen if apks could be installed without the user's knowledge. Not posted as an answer, because I don't know for certain, but I'd be surprised if it were possible.

Comment: Focus on why it is allegedly "mandatory" and find your solution there, rather than in a mobile framework carefully designed not to permit 3rd party developers to do this kind of thing.  For example, if the app is mandatory to use some service, make the service not work without it.

Comment: This is a circular question anyway: even if there were an API, how as a 3rd party dev could you make an apk mandatory except with code in an apk?  What would make the apk that makes the apk mandatory, mandatory?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install apk without user Interaction than plug Your Mobile Cable with the computer & than run your code in the sdk AS & when the project install on the emmulator it will automatically install on the Devise also Try this.

Comment: The adb install method requires that the user has chosen to enable USB debugging in the settings menu.  Plus you have to have physical possession of the device.

Answer (score 0):

Your only realistic option to actually do this on the device is to become your own android device distributor and flash devices with a custom(ized) system image where the "mandatory" apk is installed on the system partition - the way carriers do with their assorted non-removable built-in apps.